# How to print a data.frame in a format that can be reused

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm sure I've seen this somewhere before (Actually thought I'd asked the question earlier) but

if I have a data frame

`a = data.frame(A=c(1:6),B=c(1:6),C=c(1:6))`

but supposing I've input it manually using `fix`

I could potentially use `write` of some variety and save it to a file, but if I'm being lazy and would like to store the data frame in the same file as my code, what command to I use to print it into a format that is then machine readable by **R** and which I can paste into my code as

```
a = ...
```

Comment: You could use `dput` (i.e., what is recommended on the SO R-tag for providing reproducible data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `dput`:

```
> a = data.frame(A=c(1:6),B=c(1:6),C=c(1:6))
> dput(a)
structure(list(A = 1:6, B = 1:6, C = 1:6), .Names = c("A", "B", 
"C"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
> b = dput(a)
> b
  A B C
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6
```